# Check sum of tensor in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I'm new to Pytorch, I need to simply check if a Tensor built of 1D list (of floats) sums up to 10 (exactly) or not.

I found that:

`t.sum(dtype=torch.float16).item() == 10`

Is the shortest way to get the sum (where `t` is the tensor), as if I don't set the `dtype` sum may not be accurate (values that sums up to `10` are actually summed to `10.0000001192092896` using `torch.sum` without reducing to `float16`). Then I must call `item()`, as I could not find any other way to test the actual value of the sum.

Is it really the shortest way to do this? Seems a bit too much to just get a sum of a 1D array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to compare floats for almost-equality in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python)